# How can you test if a JavaScript object literal has the same properties as a TypeScript class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Goal

I would like to write a unit test to verify at runtime that a JavaScript object conforms to a TypeScript type. I am looking for a way to do this that allows me to describe the type once, and then subsequently it for both TypeScript compile-time checks, and JavaScript runtime checks. The solution must allow for nested class structures.

### Code

Because a code example is worth 1000 words... see "???" for the root of the problem:

**Target Unit Test**

```
it('object literal and TypeScript class should be compatible, () => {
  
  ??? psudo-code on line below ???  
  const isCompatible = (myLiteral ~has matching properties with~ MyClass)

  expect(isCompatible).toBeTrue();

});
```

**JavaScript Object Literal**

```
var myLiteral = {
  entities: {
    users: {
      '1': { id: 1 },
      '2': { id: 2 }
    }
  }
}
```

**Classes defined in TypeScript**

```
class MyClass {
    entities: Entities;
}

class Entities {
    users: { [key: string]: User };
}

class User {
    id: number;
}
```

### Background

I am using [normalizer](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) to normalize an object. The output of the `normalize` method is not strongly typed - and so will require use of the `as` keyword to get the output back into a strong type. This is a potential point for future errors to be introduced to the codebase unknowingly.

I would like to write unit tests to verify the output of normalizr conforms to the already defined types I am using in TypeScript

### Current Ideas

TypeScript interfaces and types do not exist at runtime... But, classes do, and types can be derived from classes. I am hoping there is a way to leverage this fact to achieve my goal.  Or perhaps there is another codegen way. However, so far, I have been unable to find one.  Or perhaps the whole way I am going about the above is wrong-headed in some way, or I am missing something obvious. Feedback on any of this welcome.

Comment: I think the title of the question is misleading. JavaScript (ES6 and onward) has classes too, which I assume are different from TypeScript classes.

Comment: I have tried to add clarity by updating the code example to be more explicit, and moving it to the top of the post. Hopefully that helps clear up any javascript/typescript class confusion a little better

Comment: I think your concept of unit testing might off, or I might be misunderstanding your problem but in my projects we use [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) which gives you assertions which seems like it's what you're looking for, you can use api similiar to `literal.should().be().equalTo({json object})` there's other api that can check the props etc.. it might be what you need

Comment: I think it would be clear if you titled it "How can you test if a javascript object literal has the same properties as a **typescript** class?" (i bolded the suggested title change)

Comment: anyway do you want to make sure two objects have the same types for all properties? what happens if there are extra properties? does it still count as conforming to the type or not?

Comment: @ChrisRollins - good call on the title change. And, to your question, I would like to fail the test if either the TypeScript class or the JavaScript literal have any properties that the other doesn't

Comment: FYI, it would be `myLiteral instanceof MyClass`, not `myLiteral === instanceof MyClass`, as `instanceof` is an operator itself. But that wouldn't work, because `myLiteral` is not an instance of a class; it's a literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project [Typescript Json Schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-json-schema) generates JSON schemas from TS classes.  These can be used at runtime to validate JS object literals.

I've used the library to validate inputs to my API and generate sane responses (e.g. property `entities` is missing on input `MyClass` object).